# inserting into table with conditions

Tags: sql, sql-insert

SQL.
i have two tables residents (primary key rid) and dependents (primary key did). dependents is connected to residents through rid. I want to insert rows into dependents table only if the rid in the insert statement matches with any of the rid in the residents table. i tried the code below, but there is some error with the where clause.

```
insert into
  dependents(rid, name, did, phone)
values
  (1, 'george', 156, 8134563255)
where
  exists(
    select
      rid
    from
      residents
    where
      residents.rid = dependents.rid
  );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my mind, it doesn't make sense to insert a value that already exists, so I think that you might want actually want `update`:

```
update dependents
    set name = 'george',
        did = 156,
        phone = 8134563255
    where rid = 1;
```

If you want `insert`, then use `insert . . . select`:

```
insert into dependents (rid, name, did, phone) 
    select 1, 'george', 156, 8134563255
    from residents r
    where r.id = 1;
```

If you want to insert *all* residents, then:

```
insert into dependents (rid, name, did, phone) 
    select r.id, 'george', 156, 8134563255
    from residents r;
```